# how to delete google analytics cookie on click of a button in javascript? all cookies are getting deleted except ga cookies with below code

Tags: javascript, cookies

I tried all possible ways to delete a cookie on button click in javascript, but the a particular google analytics cookie is not getting deleted at all.The cookie name is "_ga" & "_gid". Below is the code :

```
function deleteCookie(cname) {

  // Create an date object
  var d = new Date(); 

  // Set the time to the past. 1000 milliseonds = 1 second
  d.setTime(d.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 48));

  // Compose the expiration date 
  var expires = "Expires=" + d.toGMTString();

  window.document.cookie = cname + "=; Path=/; " + expires ;
  
  console.log(window.document.cookie);
}

deleteCookie('_ga');
deleteCookie('_gid');
```

Comment: There are tools that allow you to format code in the question textbox. I've fixed it for you in this instance.

Comment: Is the cookie marked HTTPOnly ? If yes it cannot be accessed with JavaScript

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: @GabrielLupu - the cookies is https

Comment: the console output is the "cookiename = "its value" such as : "_ga = its value". but dont know why on click of the button, still the cookies are not getting deleted @showdev

Comment: It is removing all other cookies except ga cookies. Even if I specify domains, it does not removed ga cookies at help. Any help is appreciated